# Elastic Beanstalk not deploying on all instances

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have a Django application that I deploy through EB. I had the auto-scaling policy set to min. and max. 1 instance. This was working fine.

Then I just chnaged the auto scaling to min. and max. 2 instances. The new instance automatically came up. But the application was not deployed to the new one. I manually deployed but still no difference. Tried the deployment policy to rolling and all at once and still the same.
The new instance doesn't have any code in it.

The ELB says the instances are fine and tries to send traffic to the new instance which results in a Not Found Page.

What should I do?

Update:
I found out that it does create a new bundle in /opt/python/bundle but the application is still not deployed. If I go to /opt/python/current/app, it is empty.

Update:
I can't even generate any logs on the new instance.

Update:
After rebuilding the environment with auto-scaling set to min.2 and max.2 and instance size as t2.small, things work fine (although not an acceptable solution).
I now moved from t2.small to t2.micro. Elastic Beanstalk just created a new cloudformation template for auto-scaling with min.2 and max.2 t2.micro and then said environment update is over. The auto-scaling group then created 2 t2.micro EC2 instances. It then removed one of the old t2.small from the load balancer and attached one of the new t2.micro to the load balancer and repeated this for the other instance. The events on EB reflect this too.
But its the same problem again. The application was not deployed in the new instances. Manually deploying from the console doesn't work either. Requesting Logs in EB console doesn't give anything at all.

What the hell is going on?

Comment: "Then I just chnaged the auto scaling to min. and max. 2 instances." How did you do this? Via the EB console, via CloudFormation template, or something else?

Comment: Through the AWS EB console.

Comment: Hmm, this should not occur. One thing you could try (maybe you did) is restarting the application servers. This is an option on the EB console. If that did not work, I would immediately contact AWS support. It sounds like either a bug on their side, or something with your configuration. In fact I would contact their support now and ask them to look into this.

Comment: Restarting application won't and didn't work as it just restarts the application server. But the application code has not been deployed properly. So wsgi isn't available to restart and apache has nothing connected to it and so restarting gives 400 error.

Comment: Definitely something I would contact AWS support about, this is not typical system behavior. I'd be interested to hear what they say once they get back to you, feel free to @ me in a comment

Comment: @KayakinKoder I don't have a technical support plan. So I got no way of contacting them.

Comment: I think there is some miscommunication between the auto-scaling group and EB. After the auto-scaling group adds/removes/updates the instances, it doesn't notify EB. EB only gets info from the ELB about the instances maybe. Because if I execute "eb status" through the CLI, it just gives me the instance id and status is inservice. Nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, not sure, sounds like a deep infrastructure issue. $29 for support to ensure this doesn't happen in production (and to save you a lot of time digging more for the answer) seems like a very good deal.

Comment: Yes. Trying to get supervisor to approve it.

Comment: How is your health check set up? Are you using / ?

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of digging through, my only option was to rebuild the environment (via Elastic Beanstalk Console). That fixed everything.

But this is not an acceptable solution. I was doing this in our staging environment. But if I was to do this Production, it would be catastrophic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure this out, I have the same issue.

Comment: I also have the same issue, rebuilding the environment didn't fix it for me.
After all these years, has anybody figured out what is the problem?